# Single Authentication Database for multiple applications

Tags: database, database-design, authentication

I have to design a database module to provide authentication for multiple application.
I have three different applications and each one of them has their login module with different user id and passwords and operating independently. I have to design a login system that provides an option for user to use the same login credentials for all these different applications.
This is only an additional feature and I do not have to disturb existing database.

Currently I am Planning to have a table with only required field, like
ID
FirstName,
LastName,
EmailId       ///Unique field

How to link this table with other applications?

Thanks!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't design this. It's been done.

Simply adopt LDAP. That's a key use case for an LDAP server. Stock schema is fine for 90%+ of use cases.

Comment: Thanks, this is the task I am supposed to do as a intern, so I have to design the system.